# Broken git add--interactive command after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: git

I regularly use the interactive mode of git with: `git add -p` which uses the `add--interactive` git command.

Since I updated to Big Sur one month ago, the `add--interactive` command does no longer work. I get the following error:

`error: git-add--interactive died of signal 11`

when I run `git add -p`, `git add -i` or `git add--interactive`:

```sh
~/projects/gittest[master]% git add -i
error: git-add--interactive died of signal 11
~/projects/gittest[master]%
```

I use the system git with the system perl:

```sh
git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
```

```sh
perl --version
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

My mac version is: `macOS BigSur 11.4`.

Any other git command works perfectly.

Steps I tried to fix the issue:

- Remove `gitconfig` at `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig`
- Remove `gitconfig` at `~/.gitconfig
- Make sure, that there is no local `gitconfig` file
- Use another git version installed with `brew install git`
- Use another perl version installed with `brew install perl`
- Reinstalled XCode developer tools

Unfortunately, nothing fixed the issue. I'm stuck and don't know how what I could try further or how I could debug it.

Does anyone knows anything about this issue? Do you have any hints what I could try to fix it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does `which git` give you?

Comment: It's: `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: And what does `ls -l /usr/bin/git` output?

Comment: => `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   134K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/git`

Comment: So you're currently using the system git, not the homebrew one?

Comment: yes exactly. But I also tried with a brewed version and with the binary installer from git-scm.com. None of them worked

Comment: What about installing git and perl using homebrew again? Make sure the restart the terminal session

Comment: Signal 11 is SIGSEGV on Darwin, so you're definitely on the right track in looking at perl versions. The interactive add is a perl script (there's a project in progress to convert it to C code, but the Apple version won't be using that yet). You might want to try invoking it directly—use `git --exec-path` to see where it lives—and/or copy it to a version you can edit and see if you can figure out what's tripping up the perl interpreter.

Comment: If and when you do track it down to some perl construct and perhaps have a work-around, you can file a bug with Apple (it's their perl) and maybe provide the workaround to the Git folks so that the brew install version can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it really seems that this perl version is broken for the git interactive script. As I already wrote in my question-post, my system-perl is:

```
perl --version
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

I first tried with the newest perl from homebrew:

`This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level``

but it failed with:

```
~/projects/gittest[master]% git add -i
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
  Referenced from: /Users/elioschmutz/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
  Referenced from: /Users/elioschmutz/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

error: git-add--interactive died of signal 6
```

after installing an older version:

`brew install perl@5.18`
`This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level`

it works now fine!

Caution: the `git-add--interactive` script (thanks a lot to @tokek for your command-hint of using `git --exec-path`) is using the perl under `/usr/bin/perl`. So make sure, this path points to the perl v5.18 `/usr/local/opt/perl@5.18/bin/perl`

Comment: This is probably happening because git is bringing along a perl library that links to a shared library.  Since the ABI has changed dramatically between Perl 5.18 and Perl 5.30, the process is dying when it tries tries to load the object.

Comment: I tried install perl 5.18 from brew and it didn't work for me.  I keep getting the same `git-add--interactive died of signal 11` message.  Which perl and git did you end up using and did you add any symlinks?

Comment: @daotoad Have you modified the git-add--interactive file under your `git --exec-path`? e.g. `sudo vim /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-add--interactive`


Change the first line from `/usr/bin/perl` to `/usr/local/opt/perl@5.18/bin/perl`

Comment: @superlee, see my answer below.  Rather than modify the script, I installed the missing dependencies where it could find them.  This has the advantage of fixing any other remaining perl based git scripts in the installation, where updating the #! line in a single file wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Apple ships git with a hard coded expectation of perl 5.18.

I found the `git-add--interactive` script by running `GIT_TRACE=1 git add -i`.  It told me that I could find the file in  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/`.  Inspecting it showed this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# BEGIN XCODE RUNTIME_PREFIX generated code
BEGIN {
    use File::Spec;
    my $PERLVERSION = "5.18";
    if ($^V =~ m/v([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/) {
        $PERLVERSION = $1.".".$2;
    }
    my $__prefix = File::Spec->rel2abs( __FILE__ );
```

When they updated their main Perl binary to Perl 5.30 without updating this stuff, they broke any script that has this prefix hammered onto it.

Based on this I thought I'd try adding any missing dependencies so that they'd be available in the `@INC` library search directories.

I was able to get my system working by adding the Git library to the system perl:

1. Run `/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e shell` to execute the classic interactive CPAN shell.
2. Type `install Git` and wait for the build to complete with `/usr/bin/make install  -- OK`
3. Type `q` to exit the installer.

And done.  These steps fixed `git add -i` for me.